# elasticsearch index template pattern with regex

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to provide a template to create a new index per month, so the pattern would be `myindex-yyyy-MM`. I only made it work with the pattern `myindex-*` but that would also match the index `myindex-abc` for example.

How can I specify the index template pattern as a regex? That is what I tried:

`patterns: "myindex-\d{4}\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])"`

Answer (score 1):

Don't think you can define an index pattern with a regex, but, in your shoes, I would simply solve it with a `myindex-20*` index pattern.